# Strapi+mysql deploy on Google Cloud not working

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, gcloud, strapi

I'm trying to deploy my app to App Engine but when I open the url of the strapi app I get Server error and looking in the logs I got this [image: error log]

What I can do to fix it?

this is my database.js file

```
    module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'mysql',
        socketPath: `/cloudsql/${env('INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME')}`,
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME'),
        username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        ssl: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Any feedback on my answer to continue helping would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I’m guessing you are following the Strapi + GAE [official guide](https://strapi.gitee.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/deployment/google-app-engine.html) because your database.json file looks like the one in the example. Though this one is using postgres, I recommend reading the guide on [databases](https://strapi.gitee.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/databases.html) and trying to start a new project following the instructions for MySql, or read [this blog entry](https://strapi.io/blog/configuring-strapi-mysql-database) if you haven’t.

Also, I found you have already [opened a question](https://forum.strapi.io/t/strapi-mysql-deployment-on-google-app-engine/4672) in the Strapi Forum which is great, just be sure to keep updated with any relevant information.

Finally, here is this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57692856/how-do-i-connect-a-strapi-gae-app-to-a-mysql-gsc-database) that is working with your same set up. Even though it is not very recent you can take a look and try some of their code, where the database.json file looks like this:

```json
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "strapi-hook-bookshelf",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mysql",
        "host": "${process.env.MYSQL_HOST || '127.0.0.1'}",
        "port": "${process.env.MYSQL_PORT || '3306'}",
        "database": "${process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE}",
        "username": "${process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME}",
        "password": "${process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD}",
        "socketPath": "/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}"
      },
      "options": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I followed the  Strapi + GAE official guide,  and the first time the thing was to chance host to socketpath and the deployment worked . but I had to change of account and I did the same configuration but still having that issue.

Comment: I have reviewed the guide to [Connect  from Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard) and compared it with the guide I have referenced previously, and there are some details missing. I suggest verifying you are using the correct configuration for your type of instance (private or public) and use the suggested `pathsocket` in the guide.